# Setting up nginx as proxy between webservice docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up a server to host a specific web application. I have registered a domain (lets say example.org) made a vps via digitalocean and set the DNS for example.org to point to it, so if I run a simple webserver, I get access to it by opening example.org in a web browser.

I want to use this server to host filebrowser (https://filebrowser.org/). If I just run it with default docker command, it works. However, I want to

1. have it (and any other webservices) behind HTTPS.
2. have it reachable at example.org/files. This is so I can use the domain for other things as well.

The idea is to run nginx in one docker container with ports 80 and 443 published. Then I have certbot in another following this guide: https://mindsers.blog/post/https-using-nginx-certbot-docker/. And finally I want to run filebrowser in a third docker container. This way, only nginx should be accessible from the outside and it handles all routing to other services. If I understand correctly, I then only need to set up ssl-certs for the nginx-container and it can communicate with normal http internally. My current docker-compose.yaml is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
      - ./nginx/www/:/srv/www/:ro
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
  filebrowser:
    image: filebrowser/filebrowser:latest
    volumes:
      - ./filebrowser/files:/srv
      - ./filebrowser/filebrowser.db:/filebrowser.db
      - ./filebrowser/filebrowser.json:/.filebrowser.json
```

From looking at this answer https://serverfault.com/a/813776/1037593, i have set up nginx with the following config:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.org www.example.org;
server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    http2 on;

    server_name example.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.org/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        root /srv/www/;
    }

    location /files {
        return 302 /files/;
    }

    location /files/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";

        proxy_pass http://filebrowser:8080/;

        sub_filter 'action="/' 'action="/files/';
        sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/files/';
        sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/files/';
        sub_filter_once off;
    }
}
```

And finally, the config for filebrowser is

```
{
  "port": 8080,
  "baseURL": "",
  "address": "",
  "log": "stdout",
  "database": "/filebrowser.db",
  "root": "/srv"
}
```

When I run this, the dummy index.html file nginx serves at / is shown when I navigate to example.org. When I try to navigate to example.org/files, I get the login-page for filebrowser, but when I input the username and password (which I know are correct) I get the error message "Wrong credentials", and the console from nginx shows an error about being unable to find a perticular file. The full output from running `docker compose up` and trying to log in is:

```
[+] Running 4/4
 ✔ Network webservices_default          Created    0.1s
 ✔ Container webservices-certbot-1      Created    0.1s
 ✔ Container webservices-filebrowser-1  Created    0.1s
 ✔ Container webservices-webserver-1    Created    0.1s
Attaching to webservices-certbot-1, webservices-filebrowser-1, webservices-webserver-1
webservices-filebrowser-1  | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 Using config file: /.filebrowser.json
webservices-filebrowser-1  | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 Listening on [::]:8080
webservices-webserver-1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
webservices-webserver-1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
webservices-webserver-1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
webservices-webserver-1    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
webservices-webserver-1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
webservices-webserver-1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
webservices-webserver-1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
webservices-webserver-1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.1
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-78-generic
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:49:57 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
webservices-certbot-1      | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
webservices-certbot-1      | Certbot doesn't know how to automatically configure the web server on this system. However, it can still get a certificate for you. Please run "certbot certonly" to do so. You'll need to manually configure your web server to use the resulting certificate.
webservices-certbot-1 exited with code 1
webservices-webserver-1    | 89.8.210.16 - - [26/Jul/2023:12:50:17 +0000] "GET /files HTTP/2.0" 302 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
webservices-webserver-1    | 89.8.210.16 - - [26/Jul/2023:12:50:17 +0000] "GET /files/ HTTP/2.0" 200 4439 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:50:17 [warn] 21#21: *1 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/1/00/0000000001 while reading upstream, client: 89.8.210.16, server: example.org, request: "GET /files/static/js/chunk-vendors.0f8eac7b.js HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.20.0.4:8080/static/js/chunk-vendors.0f8eac7b.js", host: "example.org", referrer: "https://example.org/files/"
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:50:17 [warn] 21#21: *1 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/2/00/0000000002 while reading upstream, client: 89.8.210.16, server: example.org, request: "GET /files/static/css/app.2991abc4.css HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.20.0.4:8080/static/css/app.2991abc4.css", host: "example.org", referrer: "https://example.org/files/"
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:50:17 [warn] 21#21: *1 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/3/00/0000000003 while reading upstream, client: 89.8.210.16, server: example.org, request: "GET /files/static/js/app.8ca2bdf9.js HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.20.0.4:8080/static/js/app.8ca2bdf9.js", host: "example.org", referrer: "https://example.org/files/"
webservices-webserver-1    | 89.8.210.16 - - [26/Jul/2023:12:50:17 +0000] "GET /files/static/css/app.2991abc4.css HTTP/2.0" 200 50042 "https://example.org/files/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
webservices-webserver-1    | 89.8.210.16 - - [26/Jul/2023:12:50:17 +0000] "GET /files/static/css/chunk-vendors.e9e545fd.css HTTP/2.0" 200 7539 "https://example.org/files/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
webservices-webserver-1    | 89.8.210.16 - - [26/Jul/2023:12:50:17 +0000] "GET /files/static/js/chunk-vendors.0f8eac7b.js HTTP/2.0" 200 251297 "https://example.org/files/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
webservices-webserver-1    | 89.8.210.16 - - [26/Jul/2023:12:50:17 +0000] "GET /files/static/js/app.8ca2bdf9.js HTTP/2.0" 200 102234 "https://example.org/files/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
webservices-webserver-1    | 89.8.210.16 - - [26/Jul/2023:12:50:18 +0000] "GET /static/img/logo.svg HTTP/2.0" 404 153 "https://example.org/login?redirect=%2Ffiles%2Ffiles%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:50:18 [error] 21#21: *1 open() "/srv/www/static/img/logo.svg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.8.210.16, server: example.org, request: "GET /static/img/logo.svg HTTP/2.0", host: "example.org", referrer: "https://example.org/login?redirect=%2Ffiles%2Ffiles%2F"
webservices-webserver-1    | 2023/07/26 12:50:53 [error] 21#21: *1 open() "/srv/www/api/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.8.210.16, server: example.org, request: "POST /api/login HTTP/2.0", host: "example.org", referrer: "https://example.org/login?redirect=%2Ffiles%2Ffiles%2F"
webservices-webserver-1    | 89.8.210.16 - - [26/Jul/2023:12:50:53 +0000] "POST /api/login HTTP/2.0" 404 153 "https://example.org/login?redirect=%2Ffiles%2Ffiles%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" "-"
```

It seems like some resources are not queried from the filebrowser-service, but from /srv/www, meaning the proxying doesn't work properly. Initially, I didn't even get the login page, and there were similar error messages before I added the extra settings in the `location /files/`-block. Do I have to add some other sub_filters? I suppose this could be solved by using subdomains (files.example.org instead), but I think this looks neater. I also tried fiddling a bit with the `baseURL` and `address`-fields in the filebrowser-config, but that led nowhere. I couldn't find any documentation about these either. I also tried this: https://nginxproxymanager.com/, but I got mostly the same behavior as when I did it manually. I am pretty new to nginx and webservices in general, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the baseURL variable to "/files" in filebrowser.json. I  then changed the nginx-config to just `proxy_pass http://filebrowser:8080` without the trailing slash and removed all the `sub_filter`-stuff. This way filebrowser handles the changes in URLs. I still get some error messages in the logs, but at least the application works for my needs.